# Order catch blocks when try to handle an exception

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

```
try
{
    // throws IOException
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
catch(IOException e)
{
}
```

when `try` block throws `IOException`, it will call the first `catch` block, not the second one. Can anyone explain this? Why does it call the first `catch` block?

Answer (score 18):

From *[try-catch (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)*;

> It is possible to use more than one specific catch clause in the same
>   try-catch statement. In this case, the order of the catch clauses is
>   important because the catch clauses are examined in order. **Catch the
>   more specific exceptions before the less specific ones.** The compiler
>   produces an error if you order your catch blocks so that a later block
>   can never be reached.

You should use

```
try
{
    // throws IOException
}
catch(IOException e)
{
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Be aware, `Exception` class is the base class for all exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Exception class is the base class of all exceptions. So whenever exception is of any type is thrown it will first will be caught by the first catch block which can catch any type of Exception.

So try using `IOCException` before the `Exception`

You can see the hierarchy of IOCException [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

They are catched in the order you specify. In your case you should put `IOException` above `Exception`. Always keep `Exception` as last.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that [`IOException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) derives from `Exception`, so `IOException` actually *is* an `Exception` ("[is-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)") and therefore the first `catch` handler matches and is being entered.

Answer (score 0):

IOException inherits from Exception. All Exceptions do. When you catch Exception first, you will catch all exceptions (including IOException). Make sure that your catch(Exception e) is the last catch in the list otherwise all other exception handling will be effectively ignored.