# Distinguish between original System.Exception and throw new Exception/ApplicationException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have already solved the question, and I posted.

For the method that mad the call, is it possible to differentiate between the original System.Exception (ie. `throw ex;`) and a new Exception (ie. `throw new Exception("Specific error", ex);`) or new `ApplicationException`?

```
public void InsertNewCar()
{
    try
    {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.Insert();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    if ( /* This ex is the New Exception */
        alert(somethingMissingMsg);
    }
    else /* This is the original exception */
    {
        alert(Something wrong generic error);
    }
}

public void Insert()
{
    try
    {
        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnString, CommandType.Text, sqlInsert);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == 515)
        {
            throw new Exception("Missing something", ex);
            //throw new ApplicationException("Missing something", ex);
        }
        else
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order catch blocks when try to handle an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609597/order-catch-blocks-when-try-to-handle-an-exception)

Comment: @Stephen, this is not a duplicate. How can ordering catch blocks be related to this? My question is not related to the actual exception, but how to differentiate between exceptions in the method that's receiving the exception.

Comment: I just now understood your question.... after reading the comment on the other answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify what kind of exception you want to catch (mind the ordering). Exceptions have an [`InnerException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property that may contain additional information that caused the current exception.

```
try
{
    MethodThatBlowsUp();
}
catch (ApplicationException appex)
{
    //handle 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //handle
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not related to the actual exception, but how to differentiate between exceptions in the method that's receiving the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this:

```
public void InsertNewCar()
{
    try
    {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.Insert();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    if (ex is ApplicationException)
        alert("Something missing Msg");
    else /* This is the original exception */
        alert("Something wrong generic error");
}

public void Insert()
{
    try
    {
        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnString, CommandType.Text, sqlInsert);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == 515)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Missing something", ex);
        }
        else
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to rethrow an exception, you might want to use `throw`, instead of `throw ex`, and catch your your exceptions with multiple specific catch blocks: only use `catch (Exception ex)` for cases you don't anticipate