# exception handling default catch Exception

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code. Is it ok to just have 1 catch exception ?. What other exception can this piece code can throw ?.

In exception handling , why can't we just have one exception and log all errors ?.

```
try {

    if (File.Exists(inputFilename))
    {
        // do something

File.WriteAllText()
    }
   else {
     // do somthing
     }

}

catch (Exception ex)
 {

  _eventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error);

}
```

Thanks

Comment: There's all manner of exceptions that can happen here, what you choose to do with them however is purely opinion based.

Comment: You probably shouldn't ask a question where "Yes" is the answer.  What are you looking to do with the exception handling?

Comment: If all you do is log exception - it's ok to catch them all. But you might also take different actions based on exception type. This is where different exception types help.

Comment: You should only ever catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully handle. Otherwise let the exceptions bubble up to a single exception handler for your app. Then learn to write exception-free code. Exception handling, like that in your question, is a real anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What other exception can this piece code can throw

You can see all the possible exceptions in the [function page (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1):

- ArgumentException
- ArgumentNullException
- PathTooLongException
- DirectoryNotFoundException
- etc.

> why can't we just have one exception and log all errors

You would like to catch different type of exceptions if you want to handle it differently. For example:

```
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(inputFilename))
        {
            // do something
            File.WriteAllText(path, contents);
        }
        else
        {
            // do somthing
        }
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dirNotFoundEx)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Directory does not exist.Try to use diffrent folder.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _eventLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.StackTrace), EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
}
```

The order of the `catch` blocks is important. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15609651/1499715)