# BusinessRuleException is not working in UI project

Tags: c#, exception

I'm working on 3 layer windows application in C#. We have custom exception to capture businessrule exceptions. this is getting captured in Data  access layer and business layer. But it is not falling in businessrule exception in UI project.

```
[Serializable]
    public class BusinessRuleException : ApplicationException 
    {
        public BusinessRuleException():base(){}
        public BusinessRuleException(string message):base(message){}
        public BusinessRuleException(string message, Exception exception):base(message,exception){}
        public BusinessRuleException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context):base(info,context){}
    }
```

In Data access layer, below catch block is getting captured.

```
catch (BusinessRuleException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

In UI, below catch block is not working. it is going to System.Exception catch block

```
    catch(BusinessRuleException ex)
                {
                    m_strErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                }
catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    m_strErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                }
```

Comment: fyi always use `throw;` to re-throw if you want an accurate call stack. (Probably best not to derive from ApplicationException  as well)

Comment: Where is `System.Exception` block? [The order is important](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15609597/1997232). Can you show more code?

Comment: @AlexK. I have used throw as well. its not working

Comment: @Sinatr: System.exception catch block is after catch(BusinessRuleException ex)